# how to click anchor from code in GWT?

Tags: gwt

There is `.click()` method in Button class that you can `.click()` it from code not physically clicked it

```
Button b = new Button("b");
b.click();
```

How can I do that with Anchor ? I call rpc and I want to open it in a new tab `onSuccess();`

```
Anchor a = new ("a", "url", "_blank");

a.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
           RPC(onSuccess()){
                  String href = rpc.getUrl();
                  a.setHref(href);  
                  a.click(); // How can I do that ?
           }

   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Window.Location.assign("url");`

Also this method can help you:

```
public static native String getURL(String url)/*-{
        return $wnd.open(url, 'target=_blank')
    }-*/;
```

Comment: Window.Location doesn't open the url in a new tab and the second is javascript code. Is there any gwt method for it ? Thanks for your effort and here my upvote for you :)

Comment: then try to use instead of a.click(); native method getURL

Answer (score 4):

Following code snippet works for me :

```
public static native void click(String url)
/*-{

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = url;
    a.click();

}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dosi Bingov for his answer.

This also can be done in pure GWT:

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
anchor.setHref(url);
anchor.getElement().<ButtonElement> cast().click();
```

(Casting the anchor element syntactically to a ButtonElement makes the GWT compiler allowing the click() method.)

It looks like it is not necessary to add the anchor element to the body. Nevertheless if necessary the anchor element can be added with (inserted as the second line)

```
Document.get().getBody().appendChild(anchor.getElement());
```